# Failed to get validator identity over RPC: HTTP status server error (502 Bad Gateway) for url (http://127.0.0.1:8899/) while testing with anchor

Tags: anchor-test

I just want to have a simple test with anchor. So I use anchor init to build up a simple program, without changing any code.

When I try to run anchor test, the terminal seems to stop here:

warning: `calc` (lib) generated 1 warning (run `cargo fix --lib -p calc` to apply 1 suggestion)
Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.14s

Found a 'test' script in the Anchor.toml. Running it as a test suite!

Running test suite: "/Users/hikari/Desktop/calc/Anchor.toml"

And then nothing goes on. I didn't see anything printed out, such as "your transaction signature" or "is initialized" suggested in the test file.

Then I turned to .anchor/test-ledger file and check with test-ledger-log.txt, there seem to be some error like this:

Failed to get validator identity over RPC: HTTP status server error (502 Bad Gateway) for url (http://127.0.0.1:8899/)
Connecting...

Does this mean something wrong with my local validator?

BTW I tried with solang-solidity a few days ago and meet with the same problem. They are all the same.

Comment: it is solved. after i shut down my VPN

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user figured it out that it was their vpn that was causing the issue